# CSS Counter Increment is not working

Tags: html, css

This is my CSS and HTML:

```css
.moving-steps > li:before {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #8F8888;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  counter-increment: headings 1;
  content: counter(headings, decimal);
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 26px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-indent: 8px;
  width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="moving-steps">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

This code is not working.

```
 counter-increment: headings 1;  
 content: counter(headings, decimal);
```

This inserts `1` every time, what am I missing?

Comment: @dystroy sorry but i am new so i learn css.

Comment: Your syntax is a bit off. `counter-increment` only accepts a counter name, and the `content` should be `counter(name, '.')` or the likes. What's the point of that counter, anyway? It seems to be the default.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should have this css on the `ul` itself:

```
.moving-steps {
    counter-reset: headings;
}
```

and `counter-increment` should only contain `headings`:

```
.moving-steps > li:before {
    counter-increment: headings;
}
```

Check out this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/my9y6/):

```css
.moving-steps {
  counter-reset: headings;
  list-style: none;
}
.moving-steps > li:before {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #8F8888;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  counter-increment: headings;
  content: counter(headings, decimal);
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 26px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-indent: 8px;
  width: 25px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="moving-steps">
  <li>First item</li>
  <li>Second item</li>
  <li>Third item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @renishkhunt - Sure, my answer still applies :) check out this updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/my9y6/1/

Answer (score 3):

Just Add the following style additionally

```
body{counter-reset: headings;}
```

then the value will be increment